# Prove that $f(p(X))=p(X)-p'(X)$, where p is a polynomial, is bijective

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V_d$ be the vector space of all polynomials with real coefficients of degree less than or equal to $d$. The linear map $f: V_3 \rightarrow V_3$ is given by: $f(p(X)) := p(X)-p'(X)$. Show that $f$ is bijective.

To show that $f$ is injective I could find that $\dim(\operatorname*{null}(f))=0$. So I guess I would need to show that a polynomial of degree less than or equal to $3$ is equal to its derivative only at $x=0$. But I don't know how to do that.

If I would simply set up this equation: $$\sum_{j=0}^3(\alpha_j - (j+1)\alpha_{j+1})X^j = 0$$ how could I show that the trivial solution is the only solution?

And to show that $f$ is surjective, would it be sufficient to say that $p(X)-p'(X)$ yields an equation that contains a linear combination of the basis of $V_3$ and with arbitrary coefficients that linear combination spans $V_3$?

Comment: To study a linear transformation between finite dimensional vector spaces: (1) Fix a basis, e.g. $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$. (2) compute the matrix of the transformation. (3) Solve the problem with the matrix and the linear transformation it defines in the corresponding $\mathbb{R} ^n$, in this case $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: In this particular case, just because the transformation is what it is, you can solve $p=p'$ in $V_3$. But derivative decreases degree. So the polynomial can't have degree. Therefore $p=0$.

Comment: In the other hand, you may discuss about surjectiveness by means of Lagrange polynomial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $p(x)\in\ker f$ then 
$$f(p(x))=p(x)-p'(x)=0\iff p(x)=p'(x)\Rightarrow \deg p=\deg p'$$
but 
$$\deg p'=\deg p \iff p= 0$$
so we conclude that
$$\ker f=\{0\}$$
and then $f$ is injective so bijective in finite dimensional space.

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand why it's automatically bijective once we know it's injective though. Could you explain that please?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ p\in \ker f\ \Rightarrow\ p = p' \Rightarrow\ p = p'' \ldots \Rightarrow p = p^{\color{#c00}{(4)}}\! = 0\ $  by $\,p\,$ by $\,\deg p \le\color{#c00} 3$

In fact we can *explicitly* invert $\,f = 1 - D,\ D = d/dx\ $ using  $\,D^{\color{#c00}4} = 0\,$ on $\,V_3$

$$(1-D)(1+D+D^2+D^3) = 1-D^4 = 1$$

Answer (score 2):

Your linear map $f:V_3\to V_3$ is equal to $f=1-L$ with $L:p\in V_3\mapsto p'\in V_3$.

Notice that $L$ is nilpotent, that is, that some power of $L$ is zero.

It follows by a calculation then that $g=1+L+L^2+\cdots+L^k$, for any $k$ sufficiently large so that $L^{k+1}=0$, is an inverse map to $g$: indeed, you can simply compute $fg$ and $gf$.

Comment: +1 In case you might wonder, I did not see your answer till after the page reloaded after posting my edit. We *sometimes* think alike...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4\}$ be a basis for $V_3$

find the matrix in the following way.

$f(1)=1=1.0+0.x+0.x^2+0.x^3+0.x^4$

$f(x)=x-1=(-1).1+1.x+0.x^2+0.x^3+0.x^4$

$f(x^2)=x^2-2x=0.1+(-2).x+1.x^2+0.x^3+0.x^4$

$$\dots$$